# Установить ChromeOS Flex на виртуалку

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

Создал по [вот этой инструкции](https://support.google.com/chromeosflex/answer/11541904?hl=en&ref_topic=11551271) загрузочную флешку (а точнее, карту памяти) для установки ChromeOS Flex. Там создалась куча разделов, но загрузиться с неё в виртуалке у меня не получается.

В VirtualBox я смог прокинуть флешку и получить такой экран:

[image: скриншот VirtualBox]

или даже понажимать esc и выбрать usb-устройство, но после этого получался чёрный экран с курсором.

В vmware вообще не смог прокинуть флешку, а аналогичный raw-образ он вообще не понимает.

Что сделать?

Comment: ЕМНИП, VirtualBox в принципе не поддерживает загрузку с флешки

Comment: @andreymal, в списке нет, но разве при uefi не пофиг, откуда? А что с vmware?